# md5sum via right click in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, md5

Is there an extension or script to calculate a file's md5 hash using the right click of the mouse in Ubuntu ?

Comment: @xain: do you mean you want *a new entry* on the *context menu* (right click menu) to calculate the hash, or do you want the calculation to *run automatically* when a file is right clicked?  can we presume you're in Nautilus (Ubuntu's default Gnome file manager)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple Nautilus script:

```
#/bin/sh

IFS='
'
for i in ${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS}; do
  md5sum "$i"
done | zenity --text-info --title="md5sums" --width=800 --height=40
```

Save it in $HOME/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/ (create that directory if it doesn't exist) and make in executable. If you right click on a file you should find it in the "Scripts" submenu.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Fedora 19, Gnome 3.8.4, Nautilus 3.8.2. I tried the same file on `.gnome` and `.gnome3`.